# PHP Curl error code 60: SSL Certificate error unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: apache2, php, ssl, curl

Now I'm running `PHP 5.6.29 (cli)`, `curl 7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)` and `Apache/2.2.15 (Unix)` on Ubuntu Server 14.04.

When I'm trying use App Facebook validate  to domain https://[domain].vn:3443. I got a valid SSL certificate from https://www.ssl.com for that domain and apache setup correctly -all goods.

But when I go to FB and try to subscribe to that URL - it keeps failing with this error:

```
The URL couldn't be validated.  
Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 60; Curl_error = SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate; HTTP Status Code = 200;  
HTTP Message = Connection established
```

Can anyone advise on what else can I try? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm understand problems of you. Please, you downloads and use this certificate root certificate bundle: 
https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

After you can copy and add file to use in /etc/php.ini:

```
curl.cainfo = "[path_cacert]\cacert.pem"
```

You should restart php after added line:

```
 service php5-fpm restart
```

For more details you can reading on `Stack Overflow`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21114371/php-curl-error-code-60.